# need bootmgr for clean install on unused hdd

Tags: boot

loaded Ubuntu on external drive and tried to boot laptop with a clean hdd, only got boot mgr missing.
Am I going about this wrong or did I just get the wrong version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a new notebook with UEFI boot? In that case you might have to experiment with the UEFI boot order or deactivate Secure Boot if it causes problems.

Comment: no it's an old one that the hdd crashed on it used to have vista on it but with a new hdd none of the previous os is on it.

Comment: Do you know if the notebook has a 32 bit or 64 bit cpu and did you install the correct Ubuntu version? Does it boot the live usb-version? Can you install Ubuntu on the internal drive? What Ubuntu version have you been installing anyway?

Comment: sorry been a hectic few months I think I tried the 64 but ver. going to tey the 32 bit

Comment: Try to boot the 32 bit in live mode first, if it works, then try to install it.

Comment: Ok I finally read the instructions for usb stick and that was my problem. Now its in stalled but there is no ui on the desktop, been working from the command line.

Comment: having trouble with ui, I think the ios I downloaded had a bad file, have installed it 3 times with the same problem.

Comment: how do I boot in live mode?

Comment: Live mode is when you just "try Ubuntu" and not install it. Do you have a UI then? Often when the machine is too old, Ubuntu is too much for it. In that case, try a flavor with a less demanding Environment - Lubuntu or Xubuntu should work.

Comment: Yeah I was thunkng the same thing